# How to handle enum as string binding failure when enum value does not parse

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, enums, model-binding

In our ASP.net Core Web API application I am looking for a way to catch binding errors when my controller method accepts a complex object which has an ENUM property when ENUMs are de/serialized as strings.

eg.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public SexEnum Sex {get; set;}
}

enum SexEnum
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
}
```

We use system wide `StringEnumConverter` so a JSON serialized instance of `Person` looks like so:

```
{
    "name": "Ann",
    "sex": "female"
}
```

Now if I post this JSON (note the typo in the `sex` property):

```
{
    "name": "Ann",
    "sex": "femal"
}
```

the whole object received by the controller method is NULL as binding failed.

I would like to catch that binding error and, instead of having the pipeline go into the controller as if nothing is wrong, return a BAD REQUEST to the client including the detail of which property value failed to bind.

I know the type I am trying to deserialize into, I know the property type I am trying to deserialize and I can see the value does not parse into the type. So I think there must be a way of providing that detail to the client. I just don't know where and how to plug this in.

I would like the solution to be system wide so that all enums are covered, without having to put attributes on the properties of the model or on the enums themselves. (This is because we distribute our API models as a nuget package which cannot have any dependencies.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on Simply Ged's answer above, AFAICS, this actually cannot be done as the model binding exceptions are swallowed (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3898)

`ModelState` contains model binding errors and you can get some information out of that. As we currently use only JSON serialization, I ended up implementing a filter to check the `ModelState` errors for `JsonSerializationException`. It is not perfect though as eg. to get the requested value (that failed the binding) out of the `JsonSerializationException` you need to parse the inner exception message.

If someone finds a better solution, I will be happy to hear.

Comment: This solution works for complex types, what if my action only had an enum parameter?

Answer (score 11):

We had this issue recently and wrote our own attribute to handle it:

```
public class ValidEnumValueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Type enumType = value.GetType();
        bool valid = Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value);

        if(!valid)
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"{value} is not a valid value for type {enumType.Name}");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [ValidEnumValue]
    public SexEnum Sex {get; set;}
}
```

The error is then added to the ModelState so you can use `ModelState.IsValid` to check if the values are valid.

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use an attribute then you can derive a new converter from NewtonSoft `StringEnumConverter` and have that check the value is valid before reading the json e.g.

```
public class validEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if(!Enum.IsDefined(objectType, reader.Value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid enum value");
        }

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

This is added to the JsonOptions in your startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new validEnumConverter());
    });
}
```

Comment: If this works then I would say that it is a better solution than mine.

Comment: Thank you but if you read my question, I wanted to do this without an attribute on the property.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read that bit properly. How are you using the StringEnumConverter systemwide? You could potentially derive your own class from that and override the CanConvert(..) method to prevent invalid values

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatelly I was not able to make this work as the serializer swallows the exception and according to this there is no way around it
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3898

Comment: Working for me and it is reasonably clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just got this issue recently.
The way I overcome that was applying

`[EnumDataType(typeof(YOUR_ENUM_TYPE))]` above your model enum.

Example:

```
public class SaladModel
{
   [EnumDataType(typeof(SauceTypeEnum))]
   public SauceTypeEnum SauceType { get; set; }
}
```

Now once you post this to the WebAPI endpoint, its validated and returns as BadRequest by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Simply Ged's excellent answer, 2nd part, using a nullable enum produces `System.ArgumentException: 'Type provided must be an Enum.'` exception. An extra step is required to handle nullable enum, or a null value for the enum:

```
public class validEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type enumType = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        if(!Enum.IsDefined(enumType, reader.Value ?? string.Empty))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid enum value");
        }

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with the [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-6.0) converter.

```cs
public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public SexKind Sex { get; set; }
}

public enum SexKind
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
}
```